# Background-size pixels polyfil for IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, background-size

I need to make CSS3's background-size properly work in IE8. There are a lot of javascript libraries out there but they extend the options "cover" and "contain" rather than a px value. As I'm using an image sprite I need to set the background size in pixels.

Here is a demo of my code. The sprite image is 600px 400px but ive set the background size to be 300px x 200px so that is looks crisp on high density displays.

```
<a class="one">Link one</a>
<a class="two">Link two</a>

a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    background: url("https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/373_sprites/angry_birds.png");
    background-size: 300px 200px; 
}    a.one {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
a.two {
    background-position: 0 -56px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rr2obdss/4/

Can I extend support to IE8 without having to create and maintain a 2nd image sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specific case, which you don't really explain in much detail, a workaround with pseudo elements may work?
Just add a pseudo element of the specified size and have it have the sprite as background?

With the right combination of position absolute/relative and z-index this could work.

If you provide more information of what exactly you are trying to achieve I will be able to provide better help.

**Edit:**

Okay, so I got a solution now. Kind of as expected: looks quite dirty.
But that's what you get when you want to do fancy stuff in IE8 :-P

```
a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    position: relative;
}
a:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/373_sprites/angry_birds.png);
    zoom: .5;
    text-indent: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
a.one:before {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
a.two:before {
    background-position: 0 -112px;
}
```

The downside of this is, that you would have to calculate the zoom factor instead of just writing down the dimensions you want to have. Also background-position would then be in relation to the full-size background.

Is anything unclear with what I am doing in above code?

Comment: Is the use of pseudo content required or could I just use the zoom .5 rule whenever I need to do something like this?

Comment: Zoom triggers strange behaviors in some cases. Thus a general answer is not possible. Pseudo-Elements are the savest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='image.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='image.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But this can cause issues if you use sprite image.

Comment: Ive updated my question. Im using a sprite so I need to set the background size in px.

Answer (score -1):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size), [this polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) may help.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: This add support for "cover" and "contain". I need to set a background-size in px.